# Matlab's Canny edge function not working

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection, canny-operator

When I try to run

```
   BW = edge(im,'canny')
```

where `im` is my image (256X256 `uint8`).

This is the error I get:

```
 Error using gradient (line 3)
 Not enough input arguments.

 Error in edge>smoothGradient (line 709)
 derivGaussKernel = gradient(gaussKernel);

 Error in edge (line 213)
 [dx, dy] = smoothGradient(a, sigma);

 Error in ps_1_1 (line 2)
 BW = edge(im,'canny')
```

Comment: What version of MATLAB is this? On 2010 this worked fine: im = imread('some_image.jpg'); im_gray = rgb2gray(im); edegs = edge(im_gray, 'canny'); imshow(edges);

Comment: Do other edge detection algorithms work?

Comment: @Anthony im_gray doesn't work, I think, for me because my image is an 256X256 image.

Comment: I'm using R2012a version of Matlab (student version)

Comment: @lars The size of the image doesn't matter. You can use it on a tiny 32x32 thumbnail or on a 5MB raw image with millions of pixels like I did. The function, though, is rgb2gray. If you load an image in with imread you should be able to use rgb2gray.

Answer (score 0):

As the function works fine for me when I tested it I think you probably pass an image to the function which is not grayscale (meaning each pixels having one gray value), if that is not the case either, try to reinstal the library because as antony mentioned in the comments, the function works fine. but anyway be sure to read the [edge document](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html) carefully.

Comment: how do you go about reinstalling the image processing library (which I think is what you are talking about)?

Comment: @lars - Start with this link: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101885-how-do-i-install-additional-toolboxes-into-an-existing-installation-of-matlab